# unx_ext 0.0.7.1 ruby 2.3.0 problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-elcapitan

I've got some problem with unf_ext 0.0.7.1(and more) gem. The gem is dependency to gem domain_name. The problem occured when I would like to upgrade my application form ruby 2.1.5 to 2.3.0. My system is OSX ElCaptain with zsh console.
[image]

The same error is when I try to install this by the hand.
I try also to use CC=clang, upgrade gcc to 5.3.0. 
Thank you for reply

Edit:
My mkmf.log
[image]

Comment: What does the `mkmf.log` say?

Comment: I added the mkmf.log content